# How can I set dynamic center point in Mapboxgl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am working Mapbox-gl.js (v0.38.0) Ionic3 & angular4. I want to set the dynamic center point. The latitude and longitude should be set based on the data in the real time data place's latitude and longitude.

If I set static center point hard-coded, when my real time data changes it will show the center as per the new markers. So I want to set the center point dynamically.

I tried the following following link,
[mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/)
I have added the real time data and marker. But how can I set the expected center point?

Actually my requirement:
**For eg: if the real time data has multiple markers in New York, by default the center point should be pointed to New york. Next time the data may change to Callifornia, that time it should point to California.
Based on the markers my center point should be set.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet is inspired from `zoom-to-linestring` [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/) on mapbox-gl

As @Aravind mentions above, we use `map.fitBounds`, however, we have to determine the bounds, we have to reduce the array of features to determine the LngLatBounds.

Just make sure you loaded the feature data.

**Example**

```
let features = [feature, feature]  // ... array of features

// first coordinate in features
let co = features[0].geometry.coordinates;

// we want to determine the bounds for the features data
let bounds = features.reduce((bounds, feature) => {
  return bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(co[0].lng, co[0].lat));

// set bounds according to features
map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  padding: 50,
  maxZoom: 14.15,
  duration: 2000
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `GeolocateControl` to find the location of the user and move the center of the map to that location, Check out this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/).

You can use the `watchPosition` option to enable the tracking of the user's location.

MapBox is actively working to improve the location tracking part. You will have better control over this in the next version, [Check out this link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/4479).

Comment: Aravind, this is fine. My requirement is quite different. Please see the updated question

Comment: You can use map.fitBounds method i think, You can pass all your data points to it and it will move the map in a way that all your data points are shown.

Checkout https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/

Comment: Great answer. One more thing I want to customize the zooming after map.fitBounds executed. I want zoom: 14.15 Since before clicking "Zoom to bound" My zoom level is as below let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
  center: [ 151.207242, -33.868413],
    zoom: 14.15
});